# Remove OR replace faulty paragraph marks using VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some faulty paragraphs, which are causing my other macros to not work properly.

1. They are usually heading style 2, style 3
2. Empty (not sure)
3. before OR after table (not sure)
4. surrounded by dotted line
5. causes the heading and next table to merged together (not sure)

I tried to replace/removed those with the following macro:

```
Sub HeadingParaBug()
    Dim H As Range
    Set H = ActiveDocument.Range
    LS = Application.International(wdListSeparator)
    
    With H.Find
        
        .Text = "^p "
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
        .Text = " ^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
        .Text = "^p ^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p^p"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
        .Text = "^13{2" & LS & "}"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = ""
        .Style = wdStyleHeading2
        .MatchWildcards = False
    Do While .Execute
    If H.Text <> vbCr Then
        H.Collapse 0
        H.Select
        H.InsertParagraph
        H.Delete
    End If
        H.Collapse 0
    Loop
    End With
    
    Set H = ActiveDocument.Range
    
    With H.Find
        .Style = wdStyleHeading3
    Do While .Execute
    If H.Text <> vbCr Then
        H.Collapse 0
        H.Select
        H.InsertParagraph
        H.Delete
    End If
        H.Collapse 0
    Loop
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

But somehow, it do not completely removed/replace the faulty paragraph marks. The above macro finds those paragraphs, add new and then remove it. which eventually removed the dotted line.

Can anybody explain this phenomena? what is the right ways to remove/replace those paragraphs. please download and see [test file with error on page 7](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P-iH0FZuuUad_1xUKvO7LSoZLXi4eztC/view?usp=sharing)

**Update:** Even I tried with the following code but it did nothing (on MacOS [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FPXw_Dehr4Jifla1YzVr4KeA5NzokN0E/view?usp=sharing)). I think it is not finding the hidden paragraphs:

```
Sub HidNempty()

    Dim H As Range
    Set H = ActiveDocument.Range
    
    With H.Find
        
        .Text = "^p "
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
        .Text = " ^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
        .Text = "^p ^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p^p"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
        .Text = "^p"
    Do While .Execute
        
        If H.Font.Hidden = True Then
            H.Font.Hidden = False
            If Len(Trim(H.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text)) = 1 Then
                H.Delete
            
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    End With
    
End Sub
```

[image: Faulty Paragraph Marks]

Comment: The paragraphs marks surrounded by a dotted line aren't faulty. The dotted line indicates that they are hidden. Select one and display the Font dialog, You will note that the hidden  property is checked. If you didn't apply that property you need to investigate who, or what, did.

Comment: yes! you are right, I figured it out, can you suggest a quick method to unhide and remove those empty/blank paragraphs ?

Answer (score 0):

To unhide all document paragraphs, please try the next piece of code:

```
Sub UnHideParagraphs()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.Font.Hidden Then
           para.Range.Font.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

It should work even if only part of the paragraph range is hidden...

Comment: Please! check the updated code in question, which take care of hidden paragraphs, I tried it on winOS it worked, but not in MacOS :( I have added a video link to show the progress

Comment: @VBAbyMBA I cannot test it on MacOS, sorry... I did not understand from your question that it should work on MAC and I did suppose that it should work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Find/Replace won't delete duplicate paragraph breaks before a table, between tables, or after a table. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LS As String, Tbl As Table, bHid As Boolean
LS = Application.International(wdListSeparator)
bHid = ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText
ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Replacement.Font.Hidden = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Text = "^p^w"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "^w^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "^13{2" & LS & "}"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute = True
    With .Duplicate
      .Font.Hidden = False
      .Start = .Start + 1
      .Text = vbNullString
    End With
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Range.Tables
  With Tbl.Range
    Do While .Characters.First.Previous.Previous = vbCr
      .Characters.First.Previous.Previous = vbNullString
    Loop
    .Characters.First.Previous.Font.Hidden = False
    Do While .Characters.Last.Next = vbCr
      If .Characters.Last.Next.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
      If .Characters.Last.Next.Next.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then Exit Do
      .Characters.Last.Next = vbNullString
    Loop
    .Characters.Last.Next.Font.Hidden = False
  End With
Next
ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = bHid
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You will observe various lines in the code that apply .Font.Hidden = False. Depending on what you're trying to achieve visually, you may or may not want those.

Comment: Please! check the updated code in question, which take care of hidden paragraphs, I tried it on winOS it worked, but not in MacOS :( I have added a video link to show the progress

Comment: Instead of telling me to check *your* code, perhaps you should try mine...